# Add new reactions with GPR

Tags: python, sbml, cbmpy

I have a model and want to add an entire new pathway to it. Some of the metabolites already exist in the model, others have to be created. I also have to add GPRs to the reactions using genes not yet present in the model.

I found the function `addReaction`, but always get an error when I use it:

```
import cbmpy

cmod = cbmpy.CBRead.readSBML3FBC('model.xml')

cmod.addReaction('R_foo')
```

> AssertionError:  ERROR: requires a Reaction object, not something of
>   type `<type 'str'>`

Any ideas how I can pass a reaction object and add metabolites and a GPR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for `createReaction`. The following will work (I use the model from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50378416/1534017)):

```
import cbmpy as cbm

mod = cbm.CBRead.readSBML3FBC('e_coli_core.xml')

mod.createReaction('R_foo')
```

This will print

> Reaction "R_foo" bounds set to: -INF <= R_foo <= INF Add reagents with
>   cmod.createReactionReagent(R_foo, metabolite, coefficient)

So, by default, one adds reversible reactions (see below how to add an irreversible one) and it also tells you how to add reagents.

Let's first assume that you add a reactions for which all reagents are already present in the model. Then you can use `createReactionReagent` to add reagents along with their stoichiometric factor like this:

```
mod.createReactionReagent('R_foo', 'M_fum_c', -1.)
mod.createReactionReagent('R_foo', 'M_nh4_c', 5.)
```

We can check whether the reaction was added correctly:

```
mod.getReaction('R_foo').getStoichiometry()
```

will return

```
[(-1.0, 'M_fum_c'), (5.0, 'M_nh4_c')]
```

You can then easily add a GPR to the reaction using `createGeneProteinAssociation`:

```
mod.createGeneProteinAssociation('R_foo', 'gene_1 or gene_2')
```

Again the check whether it worked as intended:

```
mod.getGPRforReaction('R_foo').getAssociationStr()
```

yields:

```
'((gene_1 or gene_2))'
```

If the genes are not present in the model, they will be added automatically:

```
mod.getGeneIds()[-2:]
```

will return

```
['gene_1', 'gene_2']
```

As you want to add an entire pathway, we do the same now for a second reaction with a reagent not yet part of the model:

```
# add an irreversible reaction
mod.createReaction('R_bar', reversible=False)
mod.createReactionReagent('R_bar', 'M_succ_c', -1.5)
```

Let's assume, the metabolite you want to add is called `A`, then

```
mod.createReactionReagent('R_bar', 'A', 1.0)
```

will fail with

> AssertionError:  Metabolite A does not exist

That means that we first have to create it using `createSpecies`:

```
mod.createSpecies('A', name='species A', compartment='c', charge=-2, chemFormula='C1H2O3')
```

The arguments `name` till `chemFormula` are not required. Now you can call

```
mod.createReactionReagent('R_bar', 'A', 1.0)
```

You can check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50475867/1534017) on how to add additional annotation to the species or reactions.

You might then also want to add all reactions belonging to this pathway into a group which makes accessing the reactions very easy later on:

```
pw_reactions = ['R_foo', 'R_bar']

# create an empty group
mod.createGroup('my_new_pathway')

# we can only add objects to a group so we get the reaction object for each reaction in the pathway
reaction_objects = [mod.getReaction(ri) for ri in pw_reactions]

# add all the reaction objects to the group
new_pw.addMember(reaction_objects)
```

Now you can access the members of this group using

```
mod.getGroup('my_new_pathway').getMemberIDs()
# returns ['R_foo', 'R_bar']
```

if you are interested in the reaction IDs or

```
mod.getGroup('my_new_pathway').getMembers()
```

if you are interested in the reaction objects themselves.